# Accessing process.env.secrets in Amplify Build Commands

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, aws-pipeline

I'm following [these docs on Environment Secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#environment-secrets) and am trying to access my secret in a build command to provide an api key for my Next.js app.

The docs say:

> Accessing an environment secret during a build is similar to accessing environment variables, except that environment secrets are stored in process.env.secrets as a JSON string.

My parameter store has a secret at `/amplify/{my-app-id-here}/dev/API_KEY`

In local, when I can just use .env.local everything works fine,
but when I try my "live" site I get:

```
{"error":{"message":"API key not configured"}}
```

Relevant Build Commands:

```
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
        - echo $SECRETS | grep -o '"API_KEY":"[^"]*' | sed 's/"API_KEY":"//g' > .env.local
```

I have tried `$SECRETS`, `$PROCESS_ENV_SECRETS`, `${process.env.secrets}`, etc. but I keep getting the error. I think I am not properly accessing `process.env.secrets` but I am not sure.

I even tried just returning "process.env" and did not see the key there.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue doing this with a Vite project.

I managed to do it with the following AWS Amplify build settings (note, I use a backend for the app called "staging"):

```
build:
      commands:
        - export VITE_APP_SUPABASE_URL=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "/amplify/[MY_PROJECT_ID]/staging/VITE_APP_SUPABASE_URL" --with-decryption --query "Parameter.Value" --output text)
        - export VITE_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "/amplify/[MY_PROJECT_ID]/staging/VITE_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY" --with-decryption --query "Parameter.Value" --output text)
        - yarn run build
        - npm run build
```

In this case there is a Vite specific thing that the .env variables have to start with "VITE_" in the standard configuration so I created new secretstring variables in the Parameter Store. Finally, the --with-decryption syntax shown above is needed to get the decrypted string.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to access the variables declared in build settings as shown below.

**To print all environment variables in build settings**

```
printenv
```

**If you want to print only secrets added in build settings**

```
echo "Secrets:$secrets"
```

**Accessing specific secret variable**

```
variable_name=$(echo $secrets | grep -o '"<parameter_name>":"[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$')
```

Also after accessing the variable you can use it as follows

```
$<variable_name>
```

Hope it helps!!!